How to fetch latest commits in only specific project/folder in Git repository using eGit eclipse plugin?
I have a Git repository and have created multiple projects under that repo. Now, I have all those projects under an Eclipse workspace.
The issue is that when I fetch latest commits from origin, it fetches latest code for all projects/folders, but I want changes under only one project.
I have created Selenium/java automation project under Eclipse, that's why asking in SQA forum as QA automation testers might be using eGit plugin to connect to Git repo.
